# click is not detecting the presence of the element

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Hi,

I need javascript to click an html element but it doesnt appear in the dom right away so I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  var parentOfMyList = document.body;

  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        var elt = document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option");
        if (elt) {
            setTimeout(document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option").click, 6000);

          observer.disconnect();
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);
});
```

but I get an error that says `'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement`. Why is that? The element is supposed to be THERE by the time click() is executed (I am even giving it a 6 second head start to catch up).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the mutation observer. The element is there, but you're not calling the `click()` method on it. Since you didn't bind the method to the element, it's being called on `window`.

Either pass an anonymous function that calls it on the element:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    elt.click();
}, 6000);
```

Or you can bind the method to the element:

```
setTimeout(elt.click.bind(elt), 6000);
```

Comment: Thank heavens you were there. You are always my savior! Thanks once again!!

Comment: Just for shits and giggles. Lets say I dont use a variable but `document.getElementById` instead. What is the syntaxis for that?

Comment: `document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option").click.bind(document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option"))`

Comment: It's the exact same syntax, just replace `elt` with the expression that you assigned to `elt`.

Comment: I've told you before, and I still believe it, that you're probably making things far more complicated than they need to be by using mutation observers.

Comment: Probably, but I really cant figure out anything else. The elements dont appear right away or sometimes they wont appear at all unless the user clicks something. That is making things harder.

Comment: I've given you references to the preferred way to bind events to dynamically-created elements.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Not necessarily, it was a relatively minor edit. Different answers are appropriate for different situations, e.g. whether you're using jQuery or not.

Comment: Okay, I will read thought it. Basically it is the same thing you did here by using `bind` along with `click`, right?

Comment: No, it's completely unrelated. Delegation works by binding a handler to a container that already exists. When the user clicks on the element, the event bubbles up to the container, and it can then use `event.target` to detect which descendant you actually clicked on.

Comment: I see. I will give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi again, I have been reading the thread you showed me and I still dont quite get it. Basically this is what I should be using? `$(document).on('click', 'elt', function(){
    // what you want to happen when mouseover and mouseout 
    // occurs on elements that match '.dosomething'
});`

Comment: @CainNuke `$(document).on('click', '#topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option', function () { ... })` The second argument is the selector for the dynamically-added element.

Comment: okay, but `#topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option` will only appear in the DOM 3 seconds after the page has loaded. No needed to use something to delay it or so?

Comment: No. The whole point of delegation is that you can create the event listener *before* the element appears.

Comment: That's the difference between binding the handler directly to the element and delegating it from a container.

Comment: So the code will automatically detect when the element appears and click on it right after it appears?

Comment: It won't click on it, it will bind an event listener function that runs when the user clicks on it.

Comment: I guess I lost track of what you're actually trying to do when the element appears.

Comment: Its easy to lose track. I need `#topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents` to be in the DOM in order to execute my functions. Without that element present I can do nothing. The problem is that it wont be present unless the user clicks on `#topcmm-123flashchat-toolbar-style-send-sound-btn` which wont be present either unless the user clicks on `topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option` which will appear 3 seconds after the page has loaded. Since the user may not do the clicks I need to automate them so the needed elements appear whether the user clicks them or not.

Comment: None of this delegation stuff is related, it's only for event handling, not event triggering. Your mutation observer method should work.

Comment: Not quite. Please take a look at my other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468755/settimeout-keeps-executing-the-same-function-many-times

Comment: Not sure why you say "not quite". That other question has nothing to do with event handling, either, it's about event triggering. I'm trying to say that everything I said about event delegation is not relevant.